# A function that takes 3 points in euclidean space as input and returns a direction guiding towards the biggest gap between those points

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

How would one approach creating a (calculus-) function that does just that: It takes a set of points (lets say 3 for simplicity sake, in euclidean coords) and returns the DIRECTION in which - assuming we'd draw a line - we pass right through the biggest gap between those points. Is this even possible given the restrictions of calculus? Would I be better off using linear equations? Or does this need to be solved by iterating over all the given points in a more computational manner?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking: "Given three points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, what is the vector bisecting the longest side of the triangle formed by them"?

Comment: @DerekAllums yes. Actually no, I wasnt in the beginning, but I see that your way of simplifying the problem is totally sufficient for what I want to show.

Answer (score 3):

You could cycle through all pairs of points and compute the distance between them to find the largest gap.  You can then compute the vector from one end of the gap to the other.  Find a vector perpendicular to the one between the points and you are there.

Comment: One should add the note that this function is not continuous when one approaches an equilateral triangle $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ where there is no unique largest gap.

Comment: @dennis_s:  that is true.  Many functions that depend on a maximum are that way for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a really smooth way to solve the problem. I would like to show, that multiple ways of solving it exist though, would you assume that the problem at hand can be modeled in a way that allows for it to be solved via calculus or a system of linear equations only?

Comment: There is no calculus needed.  Nothing is varying.  This is all linear algebra except for the selection of the maximum gap.

Comment: The three points could be varying. (It's supposed to be a simplification of the escape direction a deer would take given three threatening objects in its surroundings) And I'm trying to show, that using calculus to model behavior is ontologically similar to model the behavior in a more "object oriented" approach.

Comment: In a case like this the deer should care about how far away the gap is, not just which is the largest.